# Parse a date with too many days in month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Is there any way to correctly parse a date that has too many days in the month? E.g.

- `'2016-01-32'` = `'2016-02-01'`
- `'2015-12-32'` = `'2016-01-01'`

This is to support easy date manipulation on some of my JS based front-end.

This is with Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.5. I think this was working in an earlier release - perhaps the parsing rules were tightened?

I'd rather rely on a standard library and it's knowledge of leap years etc, rather than implementing this myself.

Comment: Why would you do this, instead of sanitizing your input?

Comment: Handling this in JavaScript is trivial: `new Date(2016, 0, 32)` returns February 1st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Date::_parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_parse) (or `Date::_iso8601`) to parse a date string without validation:

```
require 'date'

h = Date._parse('2016-01-32')
#=> {:mday=>32, :year=>2016, :mon=>1}
```

And create a date instance using [Simone Carletti's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35502014/477037):

```
Date.new(h[:year], h[:mon]).next_day(h[:mday] - 1)
#=> #<Date: 2016-02-01 ...>
```

If both, days and months can be out of range, you could use:

```
h = Date._parse('2016-14-32')
#=> {:mday=>32, :year=>2016, :mon=>14}

Date.new(h[:year]).next_month(h[:mon] - 1).next_day(h[:mday] - 1)
#=> #<Date: 2017-03-04 ...>
```

[`next_day`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_day) and [`next_month`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_month) are equivalent to [`+`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2B) and [`<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3C) respectively, so the last line can also be written as:

```
Date.new(h[:year]) << (h[:mon] - 1) + (h[:mday] - 1)
```

or:

```
Date.new(h[:year]) << h[:mon].pred + h[:mday].pred
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

y, m, d = '2016-01-32'.split('-').map(&:to_i)
# => [2016, 01, 32]

last_day_of_month = Date.civil(y, m, -1)
# => #<Date: 2016-01-31 ((2457419j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

date = last_day_of_month + (d - last_day_of_month.day)
# => #<Date: 2016-02-01 ((2457420j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Clean solution. It would be easier to see if you write `y, m, d = '2016-01-32'.split('-').map(&:to_i)`.

Comment: Before splitting a date by a dash, one might want to [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) the date object to `%Y-%m-%d`, otherwise there would be hard-to-find unexpected delayed bugs with international clients. Besides that this solution won’t work with `2016-01-62`.

Comment: `2016-01-62` results in `#<Date: 2016-03-02 ((2457450j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. why it should not work?

Comment: I find `Date.civil(y, m, 1) + (d-1)` a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to parse a date like the one you mentioned will raise an error

```
DateTime.parse('2016-01-32')
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

One possible solution is to create a custom function/class for date parsing. You forward the parse to the DateTime object, if it fails with that error, you can retry by stripping the day number and replacing it with 1.

If it succeeds, you add the remaining days to the date.

```
date = DateTime.parse('2016-01-1')
 => Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 +0000
date + (32-1).days
 => Mon, 01 Feb 2016 00:00:00 +0000
```

No existing core or Rails library will do that automatically for you. Hence you need a custom function for that.

You should be able to easily write the method following the instructions and the example above.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the `-1` appended at the date ?

Comment: By replacing `-32` with `-1` you create a date starting from the beginning of the month. Then you add whatever number of extra days was in the original date.

Comment: I see, that's awesome! Super easy! :)

Comment: `days` is undefined on `Fixnum` in ruby and there is no tag `rails` in OP.

Comment: @mudasobwa Perhaps you should read the question with a little bit more attention. The user mentioned he uses "This is with Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.5".

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
require 'date'

date_string = '2016-01-50' 

year,month,day =  date_string.split('-').map(&:to_i)

date = Date.new(year,month)

(day-1).times{date = date.next}

p date #=> 2016-02-19
```